# angular material mat-grid-tile height

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

- `Angular 6+`
- `Angular Material 6+`

I want a single `mat-grid-tile` to have lower height compare to other tiles. Trying to do this by setting `[rowspan]=".3"` property. It does make the tile and it's content height smaller, but the space between this "smaller" tile and the next one is still as if the tile had `[rowspan]="1"`. setting the next tile's `[rowspan]=".7"` doesn't fix it - they still the same space of full height row each.

```
  <mat-grid-list [cols]="6" rowHeight="16rem">
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="4" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]=".3">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list> 

.dashboard-card {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

What is the correct way to do so / how to solve a problem described above?

Comment: what is wring with the question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solved by splitting rows into smaller. Increasing `[rowspan]` and decreasing `rowHeight`.

i.e.:

```
  <mat-grid-list [cols]="6" rowHeight="4rem">
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="2" [rowspan]="4">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="1">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile [colspan]="6" [rowspan]="4">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
         something
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
```